# Using ajax instead of using a php file with curl to get a response from another webpage

Tags: javascript, curl, xmlhttprequest

I have a task to find a way to stop using the php curl, and I have to use only javascript without jQuery.
This was my php file and it was called by another ajax:

```
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$url ='https://api.#######.com/####'; // this is not my website, just using their api
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array(
                'text' => $jsonData,
                'from' => 'eng',
                'to' => 'fra'
                );
$data_encoded = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                                            'Authorization: SECRET apikey=###'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_encoded);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($ch); 

echo $result;
```

This is my new ajax but i get this error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure

```
function getTranslation(a_data,from,to)
{            
    var json_array = {};
    var url = 'https://api.#####.com/#####';
    var xmlhttp; 

    json_array = {  'text': a_data,
                    'from' : 'eng',
                    'to' : 'fra' };

    var json_data = JSON.stringify(json_array);

    console.log(json_data);

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");          
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization","SECRET apiKey=###");           
    xmlhttp.send();

    json_parsed = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

    return json_parsed.translation;                
}
```

If i missed something please let me know I will add more details.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it is a result of [javascript's same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

You will need to use techniques likes CORS or JSONp to get around this.  The link above has more details.

Comment: I have tried something from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) but not worked for me. Can you give me an example ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Here's a site with some exmaples: http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/.  Also note that for CORS you will have to enable it on the server you are making requests to: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: I want to create a google extension so that is the reason for why i want to stop using php so i don`t think i will have a server. I have tried this from examples: 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000

Comment: Those settings need to be applied to the server you are sending requests to.  Do you have access to that server?  If not, I'm not sure you will be able to do it.  There may be a way to ask for cross origin permissions when building an extension, which the user installing it has to agree to, but I am just guessing about that.  That's a completely separate question and should be posed as a new post.

Comment: Here is info on permission for CORS with chrome extensions: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: I have no access to their server. I`m using their sandbox only. Thank you for trying helping me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34373/discussion-between-smotru-and-jonah)